# Cells values in one cell IF > 0

Tags: excel, vba

I have values in each cells in Range B9:U9
and I want every data in the B9 cell.

This is my code :

```
    Dim temp As String
    Dim Plag As Range

    temp = ""
    For Each Plag In Range("B9:U9")
    If Len(Plag.Value) > 0 Then temp = temp & Plag.Value & ";"
    Next
    Range("B9").Value = temp
```

But after I run it, there are still my datas in each cells...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not modify the existing cells, so the content will stay. If you really like the cells having 0 after processing you need to do this in the loop as well:

```
Dim temp As String
Dim Plag As Range

temp = ""
For Each Plag In Range("B9:U9")
If Len(Plag.Value) > 0 Then 
   temp = temp & Plag.Value & ";"
    Plag.value = 0

 end if
Next
Range("B9").Value = temp
```

Comment: I mean, my datas Don't change, even the cell B9